# Rails Collection Select in Form Not Saving HABTM Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails form, the associations aren't saving when I put a multiple collection select option in the form. Why is this?

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @entry do |f| %>
  <% if @entry.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this entry from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_ids, "Categories" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Strong Parameters**

```
private
    def entry_params
        params.require(:entry).permit(:content, :category_ids)
    end
```

**Entry Model**

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  validates :content, :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :entries
end
```

**Join Table**

```
class EntriesCategories < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entry
    belongs_to :categories
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:content, :category_ids => [])
end
```

Due to multiple selection, you will be getting an array instead of a single value. So, specify `category_ids` as an array while permitting params